# How to stop a loop I have introduced in a transitional postfix-spamassassin-dovecot setup

Tags: postfix, dovecot, spamassassin

I am at the early stages of the steep email handling learning curve, gentleness appreciated :-).

I have a setup with postfix and dovecot. I am trying to migrate
my email server (domain `example.com`) from my house to an instance running somewhere else (`test.example.com`). The idea being that when things seem to 
work, I will change DNS and replace `test.example.com` by`example.com`).  I suspect
the issues I have may be transitional, but would appreciate any verification.

On my old server, I had actual unix accounts and had the following in
/etc/aliases:

```
a:    \a, b
```

so that email sent to `a@example.com` was forwarded to `b@example.com` in addition to a local copy.

On my new server (currently `test.example.com`), I have virtual users `a@example.com, b@example.com`, and `$virtual_alias_maps` contains

```
@test.example.com    @example.com
a@example.com        a@example.com, b@example.com
```

in which email sent to `a@test.example.com` will get delivered as expected without a loop.

I then added spamassassin in the following manner to main.cf, and it seems to work
with one exception.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Now when I send email to `a@test.example.com`, I get one copy at the mailbox
`a@example.com` and **two** copies at mailbox `b@example.com`.

It would seem that the expansion happens twice, which surprises me.

My questions are:

1. Why is the expansion happening twice?
2. When I change DNS and remove the `test.` from my configuration will this issue go away (that is, is this a transitional issue)?
3. If the answer to 2. is no, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the email journey [across postfix daemon](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html) before you put  `spamassassin` stuff

```
Email for a@example.com -> aliased to a@example.com and b@example.com -> final destination
```

After you put  `spamassassin` stuff, basically you put [content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter) in postfix stack, thus the email journey becomes

```
Email for a@example.com -> aliased to a@example.com and b@example.com -> spamassassin
```

From spamassassin, postfix was injected by **two emails**

```
Email for a@example.com -> aliased to a@example.com and b@example.com -> final destination
Email for b@example.com -> final destination
```

That explains why you have two emails in b@example.com and one in a@example.com

---

#### The Solution

Postfix has parameter [`receive_override_options`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#receive_override_options) with `no_address_mappings` to deals with this. Put it before content filter and you won't get duplicate email.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
    -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
spamassassin   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Comment: You are awesome. I spent over 6 hours looking for a solution yesterday.

Comment: Try to study how to reading postfix logs. All information in my answer above can be found in maillog file

Comment: Just wanted to emphasise how helpful your solution was to me!